# Android overflow menu intercept event

Tags: android, events, menu, overflow

I have one action that I want to implement so I used a theme to change the overflow icon in the ActionBar. Before complaining: If I have space for overflow I should have space for my one desired icon. I'd like to catch events and stop the overflow menu from opening and then handle the event. Is that possible? I really don't have a choice concerning the UI - one item, one particular icon.

Why does onKeyDown not catch the click on the overflow menu?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        Log.d("HELP", "KEYCODE_MENU");
        return true;
    }
    Log.d("HELP", "KeyCode=" + keyCode );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I may be trying to solve the wrong problem. If there is a better way to implement a UI with one icon and no overflow please let me know.

Comment: Would it not be better to simply remove the Overflow menu icon, and just have your one icon?